# Samba File Server Configuration and Sync for Redundancy

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, samba, synchronization, file-server

I have two boxes which I installed Samba on. For now, I have a single user that access the server, however, I need to expand as to deploy in a production network. Below is what I want to achieve.

- Install Samba on a standalone server (Done)
- Have a single user to access the server to upload/download (Done)
- Adding a Secondary server (In progress, will be a clone in configuration from the primary)
- Adding additional users with different privileges, each can access a specific folder, and also a shared folder

  `for example:
  User A can access folders: fold1, fold2, shareFold
  User B can access folders: fold3, shareFold
  User C can access folders: shareFold`
- Sync the files between the Servers as to work in redundancy mode.

For the Sync, I need to perform it in automatic manner say every 30 mins.

Comment: To clarify: you want help with the last two points; setting up permissions for users, and automatically syncing files?

Comment: @dhag, yes, this is exactly what I need to achieve

Comment: No one knows how?!!

Comment: Can you tell us where you landed with this?

Comment: @rm-vanda I've managed to sync files between server either using cronjobs or live sync

Comment: But still, I can't figure out how to separate the folders access